# Django - Creating new User object via the Admin gives unexpected errors even if form is filled

Tags: python, django

Hey there I am trying to add a new user from Django's admin panel. From the screenshot below, you can see that even though I have correctly filled in each form input, errors are still raised by Django.

[image]

I am wondering what the causes for this may be? If anyone could suggest how I'd find the solution to this problem then that would be amazing since I've been stuck for a while!

Code below:
admin.py...

```
from .models import UserModel, UserProfileModel
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    passwordrepeat = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email',)
    def clean_password(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        passwordrepeat = self.cleaned_data.get('passwordrepeat')
        if password and passwordrepeat and password != passwordrepeat:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return passwordrepeat
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.clean_password['password'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email','password','is_active','is_admin')
    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial['password']

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfileModel
    fields = ('user_fname','user_lname','user_type',)
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    update_form = UserUpdateForm
    create_form = UserCreationForm
    # The fields to be used in displaying UserModel.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email','dt_joined','dt_updated','is_active','is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin','dt_joined','dt_updated','is_active')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email','password',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields':('is_admin','is_active')}),
    )
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes':('wide',),
            'fields':('email','password','is_admin','is_superadmin','is_active')
        }
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

admin.site.register(UserModel, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

and models.py...

```
# User Manager and User Model
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Manager'
    def create_user(self,email,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_adminuser(self,email,password):
        user = self.create_user(email,password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superadmin = False
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,password):
        user = self.create_user(email,password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser): # For the Company Employees
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # Have set this explicitly for clarity purposes
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True,verbose_name='Email Address')
    dt_joined=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name='Date Joined')
    dt_updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name='Date Updated')
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects=UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
    def email_user(self,subject,message,from_email=None,**kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Edit:

```
class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(UserModel,related_name='userprofile',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='User')
    user_fname=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name='First Names')
    user_lname=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name='Last Name')
    profile_key=models.SlugField(verbose_name='Profile Key',unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
    email_status=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Receives emails?',default=False)
    last_rev_dt=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last review date',blank=True,null=True)
    geo=models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name='Location',blank=True,null=True)
    unique_referral=models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True,blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'

    @property
    def name(self):
        if self.user:
            return self.user.email
        else:
            return self.user_fname + ' ' + self.user_lname
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.unique_referral_generator()
        user_slug(self)
        super(UserProfileModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: When you attempt to hit save, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII None unfortunately

Comment: You refer to profile in your code. How/Where did you set that up? (UserProfileModel)

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII The UserProfileModel is in the same models.py file as my UserModel, I'll add it as an edit to the Q.

Comment: How do you have your profile being created? In my case, I have a post-save signal that occurs when a user is created, which will then create the profile. I am not certain that this is the issue, but it is something that I don't see here.

Comment: Yes I’m using the post save signal to create the user profile upon user creation.

Comment: Ok I can think of 2 more things to try. (1) In your UserModel, you need to define get_full_name similar to get_short_name. (2) If not done so already, in your settings.py file, set the variable  AUTH_USER_MODEL to your user model (ie AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User')

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when the same error occured, I found that I need to add password confirmation (password2 after password1) field in "add_fieldset" in admin.py

```
class AccountAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
form = UserChangeForm
add_form = RegistrationForm

list_display = ('email', 'name', 'phone', 'is_staff',  'is_superuser','date_joined','last_login')
list_filter = ('is_superuser',)

fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password','date_joined','last_login', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('name', 'phone', 'company_name', 'picture')}),
    ('Groups', {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('user_permissions',)}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2','is_staff', 'is_superuser', )}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('name', 'phone', 'company_name','picture')}),
    ('Groups', {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('user_permissions',)}),
)

search_fields = ('email', 'name', 'phone')
ordering = ('email',)
filter_horizontal = ()
```

admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)